# Grails : Writing a taglib which uses a template to render data and keep it controller agnostic

Tags: templates, grails, view, taglib

I wrote a taglib which executes some logic and renders some data weaved into HTML. When I use the taglib in a view, the taglib expects to find the template in a relative subfolder of the view. Is there a way in which I can make the taglib pick up the template from a common folder like the layouts/ folder in view. This is how the taglib code looks:

```
class IconifiedTextTagLib { 

def renderIconText = { attrs, body ->   
                 //some processing logic to generate the modelMap
         out << render(template:"taglibTemplates/iconText", model:modelMap)
    }
}
```

When I use the **`<g:renderIconText />`** tag in say a controller named A, then it expects the **taglibTemplates/iconText** to be present in the **views/A/** folder. This is a problem because I need to be able to use it from multiple controllers. I need a way to put the templates in a folder like layouts/ so that it can be used in all the views. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put template into `views/taglibTemplates/` and try:

```
out << render(template:"/taglibTemplates/iconText", model:modelMap)
```

or into `views/A/', and

```
out << render(template:"/A/iconText", model:modelMap)
```

Comment: Well turns out the leading / was missing. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

on grails 2.3.8 I had to use as such

make sure the template filename starts with underscore

```
_mytemplate.gsp
```

in your tag library class

```
out << g.render(template: '/taglibTemplates/mytemplate')
```